# Is there a way to override libata.force during runtime?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, boot, sata

I have added the kernel option "libata.force=1.00:disable" on purpose to "ignore" my internal SATA HDD since I'm booting from flash memory (to speed up the boot process) and also to avoid faulty HDDs (to avoid kernel lock-ups during boot).

Nevertheless, after the kernel is up and running, I would like to "enable" my HDD to start storing files in there.

I have tried the following command to force a re-scan ad even it the OS knows is there, it basically does nothing since it has been disabled by the "force" flag.

```
# echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan
ata1: hard resetting link
ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
ata1.00: FORCE: horkage modified (disable)
ata1.00: unsupported device, disabling
ata1.00: disabled
ata1: EH complete
```

So, I'm looking for a way to either override the value of "libata.force" AFTER boot or a set of commands that allow me to enable my SATA HDD so it can be used.

Comment: Check if you have permissions to write to */sys/module/libata/parameters/force* and if it has any effect.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "force" parameter under the libata directory...

Comment: You answered your question.